# how to remove extra quotes around the string in Json file in shell script

Tags: json, shell, sed

I want to remove extra quote from the below Json

```
{""id"":""1"", ""name"":""john"",""address"":"",""timestamp"":""2018/01/01 12:43:42 -700"",""dept"":""}
```

I am using the `sed` command for this:

```
sed -i -e 's/""/"/g' file.json
```

However it's not working as expected because the values for `address` and `dept` are just the empty string `""` and I don't want to replace those by just a single `"` which would be a new JSON syntax error.  I want to replace only the doubled double quotes around fields which contain an actual value.  So I tried

```
sed -i -e 's/\""[a-z]+[0-9]+[.-]+\""/"[a-z]+[0-9]+[.-]+\"/g' file.json
```

but it's not working either.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming keys and values don't contain escaped commas or double-quotes:

```
sed -i 's/""\([^",]\+\)""/"\1"/g' file
```

`[^",]` matches any character but `"` and `,`, `\+` means one or more. enclosing it in escaped parentheses (`\(\)`) populates capturing group 1 (`\1` in replacement string expands to it). So, `""\([^",]\+\)""` matches two double-quotes, followed by one or more characters which are not commas or double-quotes, followed by two double-quotes.

Comment: yeah thanks!! its working fine can you elaborate the above cmd? please

Comment: @ashwini which part you want me to explain?

Comment: 1st part.. i believe we are trying to search for "" and then pattern where we should not have "" or , right?

Comment: @ashwini right, I tried to explain it in my answer. Hope you understand, my English sucks :D

Comment: hello!!.. what if I have comma in my actual json value bcz in that case its not working :(  i tried this regex  sed  's/""\([ a-zA-Z_,:.0-9-]\+\)""/"\1"/g' file but some places it didnt work like "somekey":""

Comment: @ashwini then you need to fix the program giving this peculiar output.